# Exclude jar files on deploy, in IntelliJ 13

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jar, intellij-idea, classpath

Suppose that I have a small web application (war) which requires 2 jar files; libA.jar and libB.jar. I want to include both of them on build but exclude libB.jar on deploy, since it's already within the classpath of the server.

Is it possible to do that in IntelliJ 13? Note that I am not using any build tools (i.e. Ant, Maven, ...etc).

Comment: If I remember correctly, Eclipse imports the server's jars by default, and it doesn't include them on deploy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use scope `provided` for library libB.jar in tab "Dependencies" of your module.